# How to say that TV is showing a movie?

Tags: word-choice, informal-language, spoken-english

How to say in English that something like a movie is showing on TV?
Can I say:

- > It is being published on TV
- > It is being broadcasting on TV
- > It's being shown on TV

Comment: *There's a movie on TV.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly say 'being broadcasted', 'shown' etc. You may find many results for that use.

However, in the context of a movie on some channel, you can simply say - 'on TV' and the message is conveyed clearly.

> *[Gravity](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1454468/)* is (coming -*InE*) on TV

In any case, there would be some channel broadcasting/showing a movie. You can omit 'is' as well. That's how even the announcements on TV channels happen. So, the commonest would be ...

> *Gravity* on HBO at 8 pm on Sunday

---

Don't use 'publish' in this context. IMO, it's used for 'static' things.

Answer (score 2):

[Name of the show] is on.

[Name of the show] is on TV.

[Name of the show] is playing on TV.

("Is being broadcasting" is nonsense; "is being broadcast" is correct but way too formal).